# I want to create a new column with the not null data from other 3 specific columns in my df

Tags: python

I need to create a new column filled with the not null data from other 3 columns.

This is the expected output:

[image: Expected output]

This is what I tried so far

```
df['color'] = df['d', 'f', 'g'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x>=0 else 'Nope')
```

But I have this key error:

```
KeyError: ('d', 'f', 'g')
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Provide a MRE (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263)) instead.

Comment: Also don't correct your question in a comment, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74898290/edit) your question instead. (I've done it for you.)

Comment: Apart from the key error that is easily fixed: The function `lambda x: int(x) if x>=0 else 'Nope'` doesn't seem to be related to your goal? How would `int("Yellow")` work, for example?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to select multiple columns (named `a, b, &c` in your case) is:

`df[['a', 'b', 'c']]`

Comment: Sorry,but it did't help. 
Now I get this error:
TypeError: Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not.

I forgot to mention that data on d, f and g is Categorical